# WebDriverException while trying to take screenshot

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

So I was trying to take a screenshot from firefox browser and I get get the following exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: [Exception... "Data conversion failed because significant data would be lost"  nsresult: "0x80460003 (NS_ERROR_LOSS_OF_SIGNIFICANT_DATA)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.jsm :: observe :: line 551"  data: no]
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'fd9ab02a8254', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_232'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 72.0.1, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:buildID: 20200107212822, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.26.0, moz:headless: true, moz:processID: 577, moz:profile: /tmp/rust_mozprofile3kZelv, moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, platformVersion: 3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 7e2460a8-267c-4e91-9774-ad3fb5e4e808
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:160)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:658)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getScreenshotAs(RemoteWebDriver.java:343)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    ....
```

the java line of code that throws it:

`File srcFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);`

The code works good on several machines, but after trying to install on a new machine, I get this error

Does anybody know what may cause it? I run the application from a container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts, there are few things that helped solve the issue:

- check for visibility of elements you try to take screenshot of. I tried to take picture of a table and there were invisible elements and it crushed the program

  `if (element.isDisplayed())`
- brake the element and create a puzzle: taking a row by row and put the all together using

`BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(element.getSize().width, element.getSize().height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);`

- wait for elements to load using:

  `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 300);
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("report_table")));
      wait.until(webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));`